# post_type not working when tag__in is present?

Tags: wp-query, tags, post-type

I noticed that when I have the `tag__in` argument, the `post_type` one is ignored. Has anyone noticed this or knows a fix?

```
`$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'posts_per_page' => 16,
            'tag__in' => array(10, 11, 13, 15),
            'post_status' => 'any',
            'orderby' => 'ID',
            'order' => 'DESC'
        );
```

Thanks

Comment: It is not clear what do you mean in "ignored" here

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug that I have heard of so I would make sure you do not have a plugin or some other code filtering `pre_get_posts`.

I would recommend checking the SQL that is run to try and debug.

```
$query = new WP_Query($args);
echo '<pre>'; var_dump($query->request); echo '</pre>';
```

Using that you can verify if the `WHERE` clause includes the post_type for 'page' or 'any'.

Comment: Yes, somehow something overwrites it in where. But it`s only happening on this page.

Comment: What page is 'this page'? Have you disabled all your plugins and switched to a twenty something theme?